# Passing data to a webview in ios 8

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

I have an application that loads a web in [uiwebview component](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . I need to communicate between uiwebview and web loaded and vice versa.

My application works ok in earlier ios (like ios 7.x, 6.x and 5.x) but now I've tried with ios 8 and it doesn't work. I can send info from objective c to javascript (with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:), but I'm not able to receive info from javascript.

For this, I used the same it's explained here: [ios pass values to native app](http://davehiren.blogspot.in/2012/10/ios-pass-values-to-native-app-from.html). I mean, I implement:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSLog(@"URL: %@", [request URL]);
NSURL *URL = [request URL]; 

if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"newprotocol"]) {
    // something
    return NO;
} 
return YES;
}
```

When I send: newprotocol://xxxxx I always receive about:blank

I know UIWebView has changed in ios 8, but I want to keep compatibility to earlier versions.
Do you know if it is possible to do this in ios 8? What is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope porting WebViewJavascriptBridge to ios8 comes soon enough https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge/issues/84...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having this problem too. As far as I can tell, it looks like changing the `window.location.href` no longer triggers `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in the UIWebViewDelegate in iOS 8.

I found this alternate approach: http://blog.techno-barje.fr//post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Essentially, you should create an IFrame and set its location to trigger the delegate method:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:myObjectiveCFunction");
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
iframe = null;
```

**EDIT:** I'm still seeing the odd problem with this method, so if you use it, YMMV. I've ended up migrating my UIWebViews to WKWebViews to fix the problems: it is less work that I expected. I conditionally use older view controllers with UIWebViews for backwards compatibility.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Be sure to fix the original code author's typo and add a closing `)` to the end of the 2nd line to close the `setAttribute` method.

Comment: Thanks @CliftonLabrum, typo fixed

Comment: I am using exactly the same procedure with IFRAME like you, but no notification is received in delegate. Any idea? When site first time loaded `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` get called.

Comment: Just in case somebody wants to send parameters to the objective c function, don't use : to separate them, and call something like `js-frame:myObjectiveCFunction#parameter`. I was receiving about:blank because I was using :parameter

Answer (score 0):

I've used the SeanR approach, that's working.

Anyway, there's a small syntax error you should fix, a missing ) right after frame:myObjectiveCFunction.

Comment: Thanks @salvabalza, typo fixed